# Обобщение.

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

За больших раков просят 3 рубля,а за маленьких 2.5 рубля - что бы вы выбрали:больших раков или маленьких раков?

Должно ли тут стоять тире перед что бы? (показалось,что оно является обобщением)
И корректна ли здесь постановка двоеточия?

Comment: Желательно указать, в какой конкретной ситуации используется ценовая характеристика раков.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь лучше поставить точку! Первая часть - повествовательное предложение. Вторая часть - вопросительное. Обобщения не вижу.

Comment: +1 к ответу Ларf.
*За больших раков просят 3 рубля, а за маленьких — 2,5 рубля. Что бы вы выбрали: больших или маленьких раков?*

Слово *рубля* можно, наверное, тоже написать один раз. Скорее всего, при первой цене.

Answer (score 3):

1. Представить это предложение в виде БСП не получится ни по смыслу, ни по интонации. Нужно или разбивать сообщение на два отдельных предложения, или использовать форму СПП:
    а)За больших раков просят 3 рубля,а за маленьких -  2.5 рубля. Что бы вы выбрали: больших раков или маленьких раков?
    б) Если за больших раков просят 3 рубля,а за маленьких 2.5 рубля, то что бы вы выбрали: больших раков или маленьких раков?
2. Во втором предложении ставим двоеточие. Это пояснительная конструкция: содержание вопросительного местоимения  ЧТО раскрывается с помощью однородных членов (местоимение ЧТО не может обобщать однородный ряд, поэтому здесь и нет обобщения).
3. Использовать тире вместо двоеточия нежелательно, так как это ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНОЕ пояснение, а не ДОБАВОЧНОЕ сообщение.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробный и развернутый ответ.Но как же тогда "великий и могучий"? Я думал,что можно создавать любые конструкции в русском языке...

Comment: Это вы БСП имеете в виду? Бессоюзное предложение как форма лаконична и выразительна - недаром она используется в пословицах. Но возможности БСП ограничены тем, что  смысловые отношения между  предложениями нужно выразить при отсутствии союзов, а для этого надо, чтобы  предложения не были распространены, например: Эти раки дешевле - берем их. Здесь РАЗДЕЛИТЕЛЬНАЯ интонация подсказывает нам значение "условие -выбор". А в нашем случае оба предложения имеют собственную сложную структуру и интонацию - их никак не соединишь бессоюзной связью. Так что подбираем нужную форму, зная ее возможности.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите получить ответ именно на тот вопрос, который задан, то попробую.

> Должно ли тут стоять тире перед что бы?

Не должно, но может. Хотя на мой вкус обычная запятая лучше. А еще лучше, как сказали, разорвать фразу точкой.

> (показалось,что оно является обобщением)

Весьма спорно. Но даже если так, что это добавляет в понимании?

> И корректна ли здесь постановка двоеточия?

Нет. Не вижу никаких оснований.

Comment: > Цитата
Нет. Не вижу никаких оснований.
А какой знак Вы бы порекомендовали здесь поставить?

Comment: В ответе написано: "лучше разорвать фразу точкой"

Comment: Тоже интересно,что должно стоять вместо двоеточия?

Comment: >А какой знак Вы бы порекомендовали здесь поставить?  
  
Если фраза нельзя разделить на две, то запятая. Тире - как "авторский" знак, ибо в таком качестве оно может стоять вообще везде, где только есть видимое смысловое разделение.

>Тоже интересно,что должно стоять вместо двоеточия?  
  
Почему "вместо"?

Comment: Наверное, я чего-то недопонимаю. На основании чего вы все хотите влепить тут двоеточие? Двоеточие ставиться в трех реальных случаях: при прямой речи, после обобщающего слова или конструкции перед перечислением (вот как в этой моей фразе) и когда вторая часть сложносочиненного предложения содержит некий вывод из первой или поясняет её. Остальное - совсем неактуально. Ни прямой речи, ни перечисления тут заведомо нет, остается ССП с логическим выводом? Не вижу его.

Comment: behemothus, Вы не откажете мне в любезности указать источник информации о двоеточии в ССП? Помимо бесспорных случаев постановки этого знака, я встречала упоминания о двоеточии только в СПП.